# How to check for mint supply on chain?

Tags: spl-token, mint

folks, how do I check for the supply of a mint account on-chain?
I have no idea on how to do this.
I've tried using:

```
let mint = Mint::unpack_unchecked(accounts.mint.data).unwrap();
```

Then I get this error:

```
 expected reference `&[u8]`
      found struct `Rc<RefCell<&mut [u8]>>`
```

Also, in my function, if I try to get `accounts.mint.data` to `&[u8]`format by doing this:

`let data = accounts.mint.data.borrow().as_ref();`

I get this non-sense error:

```
consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived valuerustcE0716
mod.rs(98, 64): temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
mod.rs(99, 51): borrow later used here
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind:

`let mint = Mint::unpack_unchecked(&accounts.mint.data.borrow()).unwrap();`

to get the supply, just access `mint.supply`

Comment: let accounts = ctx.accounts; btw